# The entry in the Realm database from JSON

Tags: swift, database, realm

Sorry for the translation ( very bad English )

Here's the JSON coming from the server
You need to write everything in the class, the tutorial did not help

```
{
"status": "string",
"exercises": [
{
  "id": 0,
  "uuid": "string",
  "name_ru": "string",
  "name_en": "string",
  "body_part": {
        "id": 0,
        "uuid": "string",
        "name_ru": "string",
        "name_en": "string"
  },
  "equipment": {
         "id": 0,
         "uuid": "string",
         "name_ru": "string",
         "name_en": "string"
  },
  "kind": {
        "id": 0,
        "uuid": "string",
        "name_ru": "string",
        "name_en": "string"
     }
   }
  ]
 }
```

It is necessary to implement the exercises in the new format (with the added UUID field). In each exercise from the server comes the following data: muscle group exercises, type of exercise, equipment. Each of these entities must be stored locally in the Realm database, and the existence check must always be performed using the uuid key. If there is such an entity, check its basic parameters to update it, in case important properties are changed (for example, name (nameRu))

```
import RealmSwift
import Foundation


@objcMembers class RealmExercise: Object {
let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
dynamic var uuid = ""
dynamic var nameRu = ""
dynamic var nameEn = ""
dynamic var kind: [Kind]?
dynamic var bodyPart: [BodyPart]?
dynamic var equipment: [Equipment]?

convenience init(nameRu: String, id: Int?, nameEn: String, uuid: String) {
    self.init()
    self.nameRu = nameRu
    self.id.value = id
    self.nameEn = nameEn
    self.uuid = uuid

}
    func idString() -> String? {
        guard let id = id.value else { return nil }
        return String(id)
    }
func create<T: Object>(_ object: T) {
    do {
        try realm?.write {
            realm?.add(object)
        }
    } catch {
        print("error create object")
    }
}
}

@objcMembers class Kind: Object {
dynamic var nameRu: String? = ""
dynamic var nameEn: String? = ""
let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
dynamic var uuid = ""
let exercise = List<RealmExercise>()

convenience init(nameRu: String?, id: Int?, nameEn: String?, uuid: String) {
    self.init()
    self.nameRu = nameRu
    self.id.value = id
    self.nameEn = nameEn
    self.uuid = uuid
}
func idString() -> String? {
    guard let id = id.value else { return nil }
    return String(id)
}
public func saveOrUpdate() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write() {
        realm.add(self, update: true)
    }
}
}
@objcMembers class BodyPart: Object {
dynamic var nameRu: String? = ""
dynamic var nameEn: String? = ""
let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
dynamic var uuid = ""
let exercise = List<RealmExercise>()

convenience init(nameRu: String?, id: Int?, nameEn: String?, uuid: String) {
    self.init()
    self.nameRu = nameRu
    self.id.value = id
    self.nameEn = nameEn
    self.uuid = uuid
}
func idString() -> String? {
    guard let id = id.value else { return nil }
    return String(id)
}
public func saveOrUpdate() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write() {
        realm.add(self, update: true)
    }
}
}
@objcMembers class Equipment: Object {
dynamic var nameRu: String? = ""
dynamic var nameEn: String? = ""
let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
dynamic var uuid = ""
let exercise = List<RealmExercise>()

convenience init(nameRu: String?, id: Int?, nameEn: String?, uuid: String) {
    self.init()
    self.nameRu = nameRu
    self.id.value = id
    self.nameEn = nameEn
    self.uuid = uuid
}
func idString() -> String? {
    guard let id = id.value else { return nil }
    return String(id)
}
public func saveOrUpdate() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write() {
        realm.add(self, update: true)
    }
}
}
```

VievController

```
 var exercise: Results<RealmExercise>!
 let users = JSON.object(forKey: "exercises") as! [NSDictionary]


            let realm = try! Realm()
            users.forEach { userJSON in



                let saveExercise = RealmExercise.init(nameRu: userJSON.object(forKey: "name_ru") as! String, id: userJSON.object(forKey: "id") as? Int, nameEn: userJSON.object(forKey: "name_en") as! String, uuid: userJSON.object(forKey: "uuid") as! String)


                exercise = realm.objects(RealmExercise.self)
```

Comment: So what problem are you having? What errors etc and where is your code for what you have tried so far. You should take a moment to read the [help] SO is not a code writing service for class work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here would be adding a cocoapod called SwiftyJSON which makes parsing JSONs a breeze. Have a look how parsing is done in my weather app.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class WeatherViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ChangeCityDelegate {

//Constants
let WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
let APP_ID = "8a5f77889dbdb03403fcdbfe3f053215"


//TODO: Declare instance variables here
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let weatherDataModel = WeatherDataModel()


//Pre-linked IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var weatherIcon: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //TODO:Set up the location manager here.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters // specify the accuracy for the coordinates
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() //you need to add to plist Privacy and request string
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


}



//MARK: - Networking
/***************************************************************/

//Write the getWeatherData method here:
func getWeatherData(url: String, parameters: [String:String]){
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            print("Success got the weather data")

            let weatherJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(weatherJSON)

            self.updateWeatherData(json: weatherJSON)

        } else {
            print("There is an error \(response.result.error ?? "NO ERROR WEIRD" as! Error)")
            self.cityLabel.text = "Connection issues"
        }
    }
}






//MARK: - JSON Parsing
/***************************************************************/


//Write the updateWeatherData method here:
func updateWeatherData(json: JSON) {
    if let tempResult = json["main"]["temp"].double {

    weatherDataModel.temperature = Int(tempResult - 273.15)

    weatherDataModel.city = json["name"].stringValue

    weatherDataModel.condition = json["weather"][0]["id"].intValue

    weatherDataModel.weatherIconName = weatherDataModel.updateWeatherIcon(condition: weatherDataModel.condition)

    updateUIWithWeatherData()

    } else {
        cityLabel.text = "Weather unavailable :("
    }
}



//MARK: - UI Updates
/***************************************************************/


//Write the updateUIWithWeatherData method here:
func updateUIWithWeatherData(){
    temperatureLabel.text = "\(weatherDataModel.temperature)℃"
    cityLabel.text = weatherDataModel.city
    weatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: weatherDataModel.weatherIconName)
}





//MARK: - Location Manager Delegate Methods
/***************************************************************/


//Write the didUpdateLocations method here:
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 { //if it is below zero it is invalid this is why we check this
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = nil

        print("Latitude: \(location.coordinate.latitude) Logitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        let latitude = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = String(location.coordinate.longitude)
        let params: [String : String] = ["lat":latitude, "lon":longitude, "appid":APP_ID]
        getWeatherData(url: WEATHER_URL, parameters: params)
    }
}


//Write the didFailWithError method here:
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
    cityLabel.text = "Location unavailable!"

}




//MARK: - Change City Delegate methods
/***************************************************************/


//Write the userEnteredANewCityName Delegate method here:
func userEnteredANewCityName(city: String) {
    print(city)

    let params: [String : String] = ["q" : city, "appid" : APP_ID]
    getWeatherData(url: WEATHER_URL, parameters: params)
}


//Write the PrepareForSegue Method here
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "changeCityName" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ChangeCityViewController
        destinationVC.delegate = self //we are setting the ChangeCityViewController's delegate to be this View Controller which is WeatheViewController
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: I need to write data to the Realm

Comment: once you have your JSON parsed just try to get the results into an array and then go thru the array and update it into realm with realm.write